# How to check case sensitivity of username when login to a site in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

How to check case sensitivity when a user logs into a site in Laravel 5.

Below is my controller function. How to handle case sensitivity for username?

```
  public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'username' => 'required', 'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        $credentials = $request->only('username', 'password');

        if ($this->auth->attempt($credentials)) {
            return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
        }

        return redirect($this->loginPath())
            ->withInput($request->only('username'))
            ->withErrors([
                'username' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
            ]);
    }
```

Comment: i don't think there is a way on laravel level. You should alter your database column to be case sensitive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
$username=Input::get('username');

 if ($this->auth->attempt($credentials)) {

if(Auth::user()->username ==$username)
            {
                return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
            }
            else
            {
          Session::flush();
            return Redirect::to('/')->with('Message', 'Username is casesenisitve');
            }   

        }
```

In Blade:

```
if(Session::has('Message'))

                          <p class="alert new-al-er">{{ Session::get('Message') }}</p>

                          @endif
```

Comment: thanks @Deena but that message is not displaying , please advice  'Username is casesenisitve'

Comment: @Deena consider using `Session::forget('Message');` as `Session::flush()` will delete other sessions